# Code completion in PyCharm while skipping characters i.e "mas" => MyAwesomeService

Tags: python, pycharm, autocomplete, code-completion

In PyCharm community, I want to activate code completion while skipping characters. I want my code completion to be case insensitive and to allow missing characters.

Some examples:

- "mas" => "MyAwesomeService"
- "avx" => a_very_long_variable_name_x
- "avy" => a_very_long_variable_name_y

Is there a way to achieve this? I looked in the "Code Completion" Setting page, I looked for some plugins, I searched online, I asked Copilot and ChatGPT... I would really like this feature.